# Check command line input in C

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int allDigits(char *S) {
     while ( *S ) {
      if ( ! isdigit(*S)) return 0;
      S++;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i,     /*for loop index*/
    sum=0;     /*the sum of the arguments*/

    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
      if ( allDigits(argv[i]))
           sum = sum + atoi(argv[i]);
      else {
         fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s [<int> <int> ... <int>]\n",argv[0]);
         exit(1);
      }
    }
    printf("Sum of the %d integers is %d\n", argc-1, sum);
    exit(0);
}
```

I got this example from my notes, which check the command line input to see whether is a number or not. However, there is one part I don't really understand how that works, in the function `allDigits` we used `isdigit()` to check the input. But why we put `!` in front of `isdigit`?

Can anyone explain this part to me?

Comment: `!` means "not" -- is that what you are asking? If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: I know that means "not", but I don't know how ```isdigit``` check the input.

Comment: `! isdigit(*S)` is the same as `isdigit(*S) == 0`. The `'!'` simply inverts the result. So if it is not a digit (e.g. `isdigit(*S) == 0`), that is inverted to `1` , e.g. `true` and `return 0;` is called.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica suppose that we pass the char is a digit, then we put ```!``` means that is not a digit, why we would do that?

Comment: You are not *asserting* that the input is a digit, you are *checking* if the input is a digit. If it isn't (hence the `!`) -- you return `0` (false) for the overall function.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, I mean if we passed a char is a digit, but we invert it by ```!```.  So the ```isdigit(*s) == 0``` means false right?

Comment: It's like this, you have a test `if (not_a_digit) return 0;`. You can write `not_a_digit` as `isdigit(*S) == 0`, or you can use a *short-hand* notation (for lazy people who don't like to type) to write `!isdigit(*S)`. Which when you think about it, what happens when it *is_a_digit*? `isdigit(*S) == 1`. By putting `'!'` in front of that, you change the result from `true` to `false` and you skip to the next character. But if it is *not_a_digit* and `isdigit(*S) == 0`, that is inverted by `'!'` from `false` to `true` and you then execute the contents of that `if () {...}` block -- `return 0;`

Comment: Either the input is a digit (in which case `isdigit()` is true) or the input isn't a digit (in which case `!isdigit()` is true).

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica So it means like If I passed the value is a digit, ```isdigit(*S)``` is true, but since we put ```!``` in front of ```isdigit``` it means is false now, and we don't return 0 instand of we do ```S++;```?

Comment: WOHOO -- You Got It! All the `'!'` is doing is inverting the result of whatever follows `:)` (you will see it mostly used as a short-hand way of negating a test which allows somebody to avoid writing another 4-5 characters to include the full `" == 0"` or `" == 1"`)

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the help! I was so confused about this part.